# How to conveniently and securely distribute scripts?

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, security, software-distribution

When making a script, either a shell script, or a javascript module, available to users publicly over the internet, what is to be considered ?

I see at least 2 dimensions that are relevant :

- convenience of installation : making the script as easy as possible to execute once user gets a copy of it. This is relevant mostly for shell scripts.
- security : if script manipulates sensitive data from user, are there things to do to make sure it cannot be tampered with ?

What are good solutions regarding these dimensions, and what other dimensions are there to consider ?

In particular for more complicated shell script projects, with several sub-level executables and dependencies.

Comment: A shell script can be modified (including by a malicious user). So I don't think your second point is relevant...

Answer (score 1):

You may try using **SHC** encryption. SHC is a shell script compiler written in C programming language. The **Shell Script Compiler** (SHC) converts linux shell scripts directly into executable binaries. Compiling shell scripts into binaries provides protection against accidental changes, source modification and renders a way of hiding source code written in linux shell scripting language.

Syntax:

`shc -f random.sh`

will produce two files

`random.sh.x
random.sh.xc`

- random.sh.x is the encrypted shell script in binary format
- random.sh.x.c is the C source code of the random.sh file. This C source code is compiled to create the above encrypted random.sh.x file. The whole logic behind the shc is to convert the random.sh shell script to random.sh.x.c C program (and of course compile that to generate the random.sh.x executable)

You may rename **random.sh.x** to any name and run it after making it executable

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can tamper with a shell script once it's on their filesystem. To answer your main question, it would help to know what sort of environment will this be distributed over. The internet? An office? A classroom?

If you plan on distributing it over the internet, hosting it in a source code repository such as Github would help with ease of access. If it's over a local network, you might try an NFS mount.

Additionally, running a shell script should ideally consist of nothing more than setting the executable bit (`chmod +x`) on the script and then executing it. Any variables that need to be defined should be done beforehand. If anything requires the user to change it (e.g. a variable that is user-specific) that should be made obvious right away.

Comment: Thanks. I have added precisions to the question. About tampering, I was more thinking about tampering by a third party than by the user herself

Comment: If you are worried about 3rd-party tampering, the language is irrelevant; it's how you transfer the file that matters. (Use encryption.)

Comment: @chepner thanks for the comment. actually I think the files can be transferred with encryption, no problem. But I am wondering whether there isn't a risk, once the file is on the user's system, that a malicious person would edit the file, to have the script send the user's password to her, for example, when the user types the password into the script

Comment: Actually, I realize that it is also relevant for javascript modules